# Avoid executing `with` statement when nested inside identical `with`

Tags: python

I have a resource which I want to control access to to keep track of an invariant: I want to write to file whenever a certain global variable has been altered. The idea is that the data in the file should always be consistent with the data in the variable. I decided to implement this using a `with` statement which wraps any code that alters the variable, and makes sure the save operation happens.

**The Issue:** say I have two functions A and B which can alter this variable, except A calls B during its execution. Therefore, I'm trying to make the `with` statement inside B not execute when it's already nested inside A's `with` statement. This resembles the behavior of `RLock` from `threading`, whereby `with some_rlock():` does not block if it is already inside a similar statement.

```
class Resource(object):
   r_file = open("r_file.txt", 'a+')
   def __init__(self):
    self.a = 0
    self.r_file.write("Initial value : %s\n"%str(self.a))

   def add(self):
      self.a += 1

   def __enter__(self):
       print "entering"

   def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
       self.r_file.write("New value : %s\n"%str(self.a))


resource = Resource()

def B():
   with resource: # should not perform __exit__ operation if already inside A's with statement
       resource.add()

def A():
   with resource:
       B()
       resource.add()

A()
```

Essentially, I want "New Value : ..." to appear once in `r_file.txt` (because it has only been accessed during one operation, A, even if that operation includes operation B). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Why not just use `RLock`, that's what its for. With `RLock`, exiting the nested `with` does not release the lock.

Comment: @AChampion `with f:` is not meaningless at all and you don't have to get a new object if `__enter__` returns `self`. This includes for locks, e.g. [the docs clearly show `with some_lock:`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html#using-locks-conditions-and-semaphores-in-the-with-statement).

Comment: EDIT: just realised a boolean is not enough, you need a count. Will write an answer now.

Comment: I've added a MCVE

Comment: a counter which only allows `__exit__` operations to run when it reaches 0 should do the trick @AlexHall.=

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Resource(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._with_count = 0

    def __enter__(self):
        print("Doing enter stuff")
        self._with_count += 1
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self._with_count -= 1
        assert self._with_count >= 0
        if self._with_count == 0:
            print("Doing exit stuff")


resource = Resource()

with resource:
    with resource:
        pass
```

Output:

```
Doing enter stuff
Doing enter stuff
Doing exit stuff
```

Comment: @DanD.  counter is enough for my case. What's an example case where a state object would be needed?